# Django Filters.py Get Current user

Tags: python, filter, request, django-filter

```
class CustomerFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    employee_name=django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(field_name='officer', empty_label="Employee")

class Meta:
    model = create_customer
    fields = ''

def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.employee_name.queryset = add_employee.objects.filter(branch=self.request.user.add_employee.branch)
```

**self.request.user**
it's get 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'

Comment: you would be able to use self.requets in APIView, not anywhere else

Comment: But I want to filter the objects based on the current user like WSGI request how to get in django_filters.Filterset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We Need to Put Directly in to the **def(request):** for get *WSGI*

```
def view(request):
    class CustomerFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
            employee_name=django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(field_name='officer', queryset=add_employee.objects.filter(branch=request.user.add_employee.branch), empty_label="Employee") 
            class Meta:
                    model = create_customer
                    fields = ''
```